# Can't apply live wallpaper

Tags: android, service, wallpaper

`java.lang.SecurityException: Selected service does not require android.permission.BIND_WALLPAPER`

So this does work:

```
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon"
    android:label="Wallpaper"
    android:permission="android.permission.BIND_WALLPAPER">
```

However, your app is essentially JUST a wallpaper in this scenario. My app is fully fledged with a wallpaper bundled in it. If I use the above, it will not let me run the app itself. Just set a wallpaper.

So I tried:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BIND_WALLPAPER" />
```

Which gives the error shown. I can see the preview running fine, but as soon as I hit apply, or settings. BOOM HEADSHOT!

Oh and of course, Ive tried it without permissions set with the same error

How Do I still run the app, plus allow use of bundled wallpaper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Android maninfest.permissions doc

> String:   [BIND_WALLPAPER](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#BIND_WALLPAPER):    Must be required by a WallpaperService, to ensure that only the system can bind to it.

So infact, if you add the permission to your service. It works fine. It is a security exception to make sure the system can only bind to it.

```
    <service android:name=".LiveWallpaper"
        android:label="Wallpaper"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:permission="android.permission.BIND_WALLPAPER">
```

Answer (score 1):

permission and uses-permission are two opposite concepts :

- permission requires that whoever calls the elements has this permission
- uses-permission asks the system to give this permission to the element

did you try to put the permission element in the concerned activity ?